# How can a thread object access the methods of the associated object?

Tags: java, multithreading, matrix

I have a 2d matrix of random integers. I want to find min and max value in each row (each row done by a different thread) and then I want to collate the results and find min and max in all the matrix. This is the code in main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double maxGlob = 0.0;//max in all matrix
    double minGlob = 1.0;//min in all matrix

    makeData m = new makeData();
    Double[][] x = m.generateData(100, 200);//generate matrix
    Thread[] t = new MinMaxFinder[100];//make hundred threads - MinMaxFinder extends Thread

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        t[i] = new MinMaxFinder(x[i], " and I'm thread: " + i);
        t[i].start();

    }//end of for

    try{

        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            t[i].join();//wait for thread i when finished
            if(t[i].findMax() > maxGlob) //this is the problem, I can't access findMax which is in MinMaxFinder
                maxGlob = t[i].findMax();
            if(t[i].findMin() < minGlob) //same with min
                minGlob = t[i].findMin();
        }
    }catch(InterruptedException e){}
        //when done with all threads, print global max and min values for all matrix
        System.out.println("Max is: " + maxGlob + " and min is: " + minGlob);       
}//end of main
```

Comment: It depresses me that this non-question got an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

100 threads is *insane* for what you're trying to do.  I doubt you could justify using one thread for the kind of overhead you'd get just to create one.  Lets not mention that allocating space for 100x200 randoms is not strictly necessary.  You could simply call random 20k times and perform the same calculations on those values.

However, lets assume for a second that this is a learning exercise.  If you're looking to perform calculations in parallel, then you need to arbitrarily subdivide your grid so that each thread has its own section without overlap.  Then in order to use it in the thread, you simply need to pass that instance it to your MinMaxFinder thread.

So something like:

```
class MinMaxFinder extends Thread {
    private int minRow, maxRow, minColumn, maxColumn;
    private Double[][] grid;

    public MinMaxFinder(Double[][] grid) {
        this.grid = grid;
    }

    public void start(int minRow, int maxRow, int minColumn, int maxColumn) {
         this.minRow = minRow;
         this.maxRow = maxRow;
         this.minColumn = minColumn;
         this.maxColumn = maxColumn;

         super.start();
    }

    public void start() {
         // perform search
    }
}
```

There is nothing magical happening here.  So long as you aren't writing to the grid and you aren't overlapping the grid, there is no risk of concurrency problems.

I would recommend you look into [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) when dealing with large number of threads.  It has a number of helpful methods for organizing threads and potentially reusing them as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to collect results from parallel threads I suggest to use the `Future` abstraction. In particular I would do this with the help of `FutureTask` utility.

```
public class RandomMatrixMinMax {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double maxGlob = 0.0;// max in all matrix
        double minGlob = 1.0;// min in all matrix

        final Double[][] x = generateData(100, 200);// generate matrix
        final MinMaxFinderTask[] t = new MinMaxFinderTask[100];// make hundred
                                                                // threads -
        // MinMaxFinder extends Thread

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            t[i] = new MinMaxFinderTask(x[i]);
            new Thread(t[i]).start();
        } // end of for

        try {

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                if (t[i].get().getMax() > maxGlob) {
                    maxGlob = t[i].get().getMax();
                }
                if (t[i].get().getMin() < minGlob) {
                    minGlob = t[i].get().getMin();
                }
            }

        } catch (final InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        }
        // when done with all threads, print global max and min values for all
        // matrix
        System.out.println("Max is: " + maxGlob + " and min is: " + minGlob);

    }// end of main

    private static Double[][] generateData(int rows, int cols) {
        final Double[][] randomMatrix = new Double[rows][cols];
        final Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
                randomMatrix[j][i] = random.nextDouble();
            }
        }
        return randomMatrix;
    }

    private static class MinMaxResult {
        private Double min;
        private Double max;

        public MinMaxResult(Double min, Double max) {
            this.min = min;
            this.max = max;
        }

        public Double getMin() {
            return min;
        }

        public void setMin(Double min) {
            this.min = min;
        }

        public Double getMax() {
            return max;
        }

        public void setMax(Double max) {
            this.max = max;
        }
    }

    private static class MinMaxFinderTask extends FutureTask<MinMaxResult> {

        public MinMaxFinderTask(Double[] row) {
            super(new MinMaxCalculator(row));
        }

    }

    private static class MinMaxCalculator implements Callable<MinMaxResult> {

        private final Double[] row;

        public MinMaxCalculator(Double[] row) {
            this.row = row;
        }

        @Override
        public MinMaxResult call() throws Exception {
            Double min = row[0];
            Double max = row[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < row.length; i++) {
                if (row[i] < min) {
                    min = row[i];
                }
                if (row[i] > max) {
                    max = row[i];
                }
            }
            return new MinMaxResult(min, max);
        }
    }

}
```

Anyway I agree with Neil, 100 threads for this simple task are too much. As an alternative to `ThreadPoolExecutor` you can delegate the parallelism of the computation to the new Stream API introduced with Java 8.

In Java 8 your application could be:

```
public class RandomMatrixMinMax {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Double[][] x = generateData(100, 200);
        // obtain an array with min/max of each row of the matrix. The
        // intermediate operation 'parallel' makes the computation parallel.
        final MinMaxResult[] rowResults = Arrays.stream(x).parallel()
                .map(row -> new MinMaxResult(Arrays.stream(row).min(Double::compare).get(),
                        Arrays.stream(row).max(Double::compare).get()))
                .toArray(size -> new MinMaxResult[size]);
        final Double maxGlob = Arrays.stream(rowResults).map(MinMaxResult::getMax).max(Double::compare).get();
        final Double minGlob = Arrays.stream(rowResults).map(MinMaxResult::getMin).min(Double::compare).get();
        System.out.println("Max is: " + maxGlob + " and min is: " + minGlob);
    }

    private static Double[][] generateData(int rows, int cols) {
        final Double[][] randomMatrix = new Double[rows][cols];
        final Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
                randomMatrix[j][i] = random.nextDouble();
            }
        }
        return randomMatrix;
    }

    private static class MinMaxResult {
        private Double min;
        private Double max;

        public MinMaxResult(Double min, Double max) {
            this.min = min;
            this.max = max;
        }

        public Double getMin() {
            return min;
        }

        public void setMin(Double min) {
            this.min = min;
        }

        public Double getMax() {
            return max;
        }

        public void setMax(Double max) {
            this.max = max;
        }
    }
}
```